# Unable to mount FSx on EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: linux, mount, amazon-web-services, cifs

I'm trying to mount Amazon FSx on Ubuntu using below command but getting an error as given below

Command: `sudo mount -t cifs -o vers=3.0,sec=krb5,cruid=Admin@test.com //fs-of760d3a18765yh8u.test.com/share /home/ubuntu/mansing/`

Error: `mount error(126): Required key not available`

Before this, I have joined the ubuntu machine to the domain (Directory Service).

I have referred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631589/mount-error126-required-key-not-available-with-cifs-kerberos  but did not help.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Why are you specifying "Admin@test.com" as a cruid? It's not a number.

Comment: that is the credentials to authenticate the FSx (File system on AWS)

Comment: But that's not what the cruid= option is for. (You don't specify the credentials in it; you specify the Linux UID which owns the credentials.) Which user did you run `kinit` as?

Comment: @grawity- Sorry for the delay in reply buddy, I was off for a week. I'm going to check this again and shall let you know my further findings.

Comment: Hi, I have provided the UID to cruid but did not work and same error. I am running with root. Any solution?

Comment: Does your system log have any messages from "cifs.upcall"?

Comment: ```cifs.upcall: key description: cifs.spnego;0;0;39010000;ver=0x2;host=fs-234frt533abc94.audit-kmpg.com;ip4=**.**.**.**;sec=krb5;uid=0x0;creduid=0x0;user=root;pid=0x16ba
cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: scandir error on directory '/run/user/0': No such file or directory
cifs.upcall: handle_krb5_mech: getting service ticket for fs-234frt533abc94.audit-kmpg.com
cifs.upcall: cifs_krb5_get_req: unable to get client principal name
cifs.upcall: handle_krb5_mech: failed to obtain service ticket (-1765328189)
cifs.upcall: Unable to obtain service ticket
cifs.upcall: Exit status -1765328189```

Comment: From the upcall logs _(please put long outputs in your main post next time, makes them easier to read)_ it looks like it's simply not finding your actual Kerberos credentials themselves. Have you ran `kinit` to obtain them?

Comment: Many thanks. That really helped, after I executed kinit with my domain admin user it has created the required ticket and I am now able to map the drive. Thank you, I have accepted your solution.
p.s. I will remember to include the log file going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kerberos software expects to find your credentials (the TGT) already present on the system.

- For interactive sessions usually you run **`kinit`** to obtain a TGT with your password (or the system does it automatically for you if it's a console login). Use `klist` to see what tickets you currently have.

  kinit stores the ticket in `/run/user/<cruid>/krb5cc` or `/tmp/krb5cc_<cruid>`, and cifs.upcall expects to find it there already.
- For services and mounts, usually you configure either [`k5start`](https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/kstart/) or a cronjob with `kinit -t ...` to obtain the ticket with a *keytab* on startup and keep it refreshed. (The keytab can be created from a password.)

  (**Note:** Although kinit works as a one-time method, the problem is that the TGT **expires** in less than a day and needs to be periodically refreshed. For example, if the system loses the SMB connection for some reason, it'll need a valid TGT when re-establishing the mount.)

Comment: Awesome! That helped and fixed my issue after I ran kinit and passing UID to cruid fixed the problem. My knowledge around the kinit is very limited, I will read through it. 

Many thanks.

Comment: Remember to set up part 2 (automatic kinit on startup and automatic ticket refresh), otherwise you'll have new connection problems after a while.